# How would I update an angle, but only within a certain range?

Tags: math, rotation, language-agnostic, angle

Basically, I have an angle that can only change a certain "turn radius" (say, 60/256 of a rotation) each time it updates. It is changed by an input angle that could be any angle. I need to clamp this input angle so that if it is outside of the turn radius, it will go to the nearest valid angle

For example:

- Turn radius: 4°
- Original angle = 0°
- Input angle = 180.01°
- **Output angle = -4° or 356°** (actual output should be within `[0, 360)` of course)

or

- Turn radius: 4°
- Original angle = 0°
- Input angle = 179.99°
- **Output angle = 4°**

or

- Turn radius: 4°
- Original angle = 45°
- Input angle = 46°
- **Output angle = 46°**

I am not sure exactly how to properly wrap the angle, so I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: Your examples and problem explanation are not clear. Try to reformulate

Comment: I agree with MBo, it is absolutely not clear why 179.99° got converted to 4° and 180.01° was converted to 356°. And in the 3rd example why 45° is changed at all?

Comment: what is turn radius (as you set degrees as units it is unclear as radius is length not angle)? maybe image of what are you trying to encode would help more ... As MBO comment it is unclear how your clamping rules work ... did they depend on previous value or just the new value. Why inputting ~180 deg value get clamped to ~0 or ~360 instead of  ~180 (eben if it would additive you do it also for original angle `0` )? maybe adding plot covering whole range will show us what you are not capable of writing as text

Comment: @kreaTTo "Turn radius" does not mean what you seem to think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the difference between the original angle and the input angle. (Just subtract.)
Then, "normalize" this difference to between -180 degrees and 180 degrees.

```
normalized_difference = (((( raw_difference % 360) + 540) % 360) - 180)
```

Then, if the "normalized" difference is outside the desired range, change it to be within range. Then add the (possibly changed) normalized difference to the original angle to get the output angle. If you wish to normalize the output angle to between 0 degrees and 359.99... degrees, you can do it thus:

```
normalized_angle = (((raw_angle % 360) + 360) % 360)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @robert-lozyniak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226366/7817457), this is what I ended up with:

```rust
fn clamp_angle_update(angle: u8, target: u8, limit: u8) -> u8 {
    let mut difference = target as isize - angle as isize;

    // normalize the difference
    difference += 256 + 256 / 2;
    difference %= 256;
    difference -= 256 / 2;

    let limit = limit as isize;
    difference = if difference > limit {
        limit
    } else if difference < -limit {
        -limit
    } else { difference };

    // add the difference to the original angle
    let mut angle = angle as isize + difference;

    // normalize the angle
    angle %= 256;
    angle += 256;
    angle %= 256;

    angle as u8
}
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @RobertLozyniak Rust